# how to use split when the string is seperated by more than one character in python

Tags: python

I am currently using python and i have a question:
if we have a string that is separated by multiple characters for example:

```
l = ['0 , hellp,\t2,\t BB , -\n', ' 1 ,\t \t knock \t , BB,N,- ]
```

and I want show it in this way:

```
0,hellp,2,BB,-
1,knock,BB,N,-
```

how would the coding be if i wanted to use split?
i have already tried this code:

```
l = ['0 , hellp,\t2,\t BB , -\n', ' 1 ,\t \t knock \t , BB,N,- ]
replacements=('\t',' ' ,'\n')
     for r in replacements :
         l = l.replace(r,' ') 
words =l.split()
print(words)
```

but it didnt work out like how i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using regex**. You can use `re.split` to plit by multiple chars.

**Ex:**

```
import re
l = ['0 , hellp,\t2,\t BB , -\n', ' 1 ,\t \t knock \t , BB,N,-' ]
for i in l:
    val = ",".join(re.split(",\t", i.strip())).replace(" ", "")  #split by comma(,) & tab(\t)
    print(re.sub('\s+',"", val))    #replace space
```

**Output:**

```
0,hellp,2,BB,-
1,knock,BB,N,-
```

Comment: but if you use that way then the each letter will be printed in a new line it will not be separated by the \n

Comment: @Johnsteven. Sorry i do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
l = ['0 , hellp,\t2,\t BB , -\n', ' 1 ,\t \t knock \t , BB,N,- ']
new_l = [','.join(filter(None, re.split('[\s,\t\n]+', i))) for i in l]
```

Output:

```
['0,hellp,2,BB,-', '1,knock,BB,N,-']
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be expressed fairly simply using `re.subn`.

```
>>> import re
>>> l = ['0 , hellp,\t2,\t BB , -\n', ' 1 ,\t \t knock \t , BB,N,- ']
>>> for item in l:
...     re.subn(r'\s', '', item)[0]
... 
'0,hellp,2,BB,-'
'1,knock,BB,N,-'
```